# Как можно вернуть значение из viewModelScope.launch?

Tags: android, kotlinx-coroutines

Подскажите способы вернуть значение в MainActivity из:

```
private val _state = MutableStateFlow<State>(State.Default)
val state = _state.asStateFlow()
private val _error = Channel<String>()

fun onSearchClick(text: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        if (text.isBlank()){
            val searchError = "Введите значение"
            _state.value = State.Error(searchError)
            _error.send("Строка пуста")
        } else {
            _state.value = State.Loading
            try {
                repository.getData(text)
                _state.value = State.Success
            }catch (ex: Exception){
                _error.send(ex.toString())
                _state.value = State.Error(null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: С чем именно проблема? Значение устанавливается в _state , либо в _error, в активити вам нужно на них подписаться

Comment: Вы в активт можете подписаться = viewMModel.state.observe...